# how to make createdtime field in Vtiger CRM editable?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

Does anyone know how to make createdtime field in Vtiger CRM editable so user can change createdtime field in user interface?

Comment: hello is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you tried by changing displaytype=2 for createdtime  field?

Comment: helo sAcH, i have tried to change displaytipe=2 but it still not editable. can anyone else help me?

Answer (score 0):

use the following sql command

```
UPDATE `vtiger_field` SET `displaytype` = '1' WHERE `columnname` = 'createdtime'
```